# How to reference a module at pr level instead of version

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform newbie here. I'm testing/debugging an issue with a module (separate repo). How to reference a module at pr level vs versions `source= <url>?ref=v1.0`

I tried `source=<url>?ref=sha` failed

Any help would be appreciated

```
Update

Problem solved. I was not aware, I could call all modules locally
*source=pwd/path_module*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your Terraform Module is into a separate repo, you can take the same URL used to `git clone` with SSH connection, and then create tags for each [release](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/releases.html) you do (tags and releases are similar on GitHub).
It could look like this:

```
module "aws-bucket-s3" {
  source  = "git@gitlab.com:project-name/terraform-aws-module-bucket-s3.git"
  version = "2.0.0"
```

Git submodules can be used to link Terraform instantiation code with Terraform Modules. But it's not required; you can [read more Submodules here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thank you for link The issue here working on two modules at the same time. I solved issue by calling modules locally `source= local_path/module`